# iOS UIContainerView and UIScrollView scrolling issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

Problem with container view inside scrollview.

I have one mainviewcontroller which has below controls

```
MainViewController

    UIScrollView
      --->UIImageView
      --->UIButton
      --->UIContainerView

ChildViewController

    UIScrollView
      --->UIView with some controls
```

What i need to achieve

First ChildViewController's Scrollview scrolling should be disabled and MainViewController's scrollview scrolling should be enabled. While scrolling when UIbutton touches the top bar (y=0) then scrollview of mainviewcontroller to be disabled and scrollview of childviewcontroller to be turned on and user can scroll the childviewcontroller.

Now when user scroll's the childviewcontroller and when scrollview's contentOffset.y value is less than or equal to 1 then i need to turn on the mainviewcontroller scrollview.

I have achieved the above condition with scrollViewDidScroll event of both the view controllers. but scrolling is not smooth. Scrolling gets stuck when childviewcontroller scrollview contentOffset.y value reaches to less than 1. Sometimes it turns on the mainviewcontroller scrollview and sometimes it doesn't.

Kindly help.